# Concatenate a list inside viewmodel in Linq?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

**Dbstructure is**

- CourseTable

  ```
  Id       Name     

  1        Linux
  2        Apache
  3        MySql
  4        Python
  ```
- MultiCourseTable

  ```
  Id       Name      
  1        LAMP
  ```
- MultiCourseDetailsTable

  ```
   Id      MultiCourseId     CourseId   
   1           1               1
   2           1               2
   3           1               3
   4           1               4
  ```

**Ouptut View should be**

```
    Name      Courses  
    LAMP      Linux,Apache,MySql,Python
```

How can I acheive the above using Linq. I have tried the following but couldnot get the desired result.

```
 var _dTableMultiCourse = _db.MultiCourses
                                    .Where(x => Id == 0 || x.Id == Id)
                                    .AsEnumerable()
                                    .Select(x => new
                                    {
                                        SlNo = "",
                                        Title = x.CourseSubTitle.Name,
                                        Courses = x.MultiCourseDetails
                                                 .Select(m=>m.Course.Name)
                                                 .Join(','),                                          
                                        Id = x.Id
                                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Join` on an enumerable is completely different from `string.Join`, which is what you're looking for.

```
Courses = string.Join(",", x.MultiCourseDetails.Select(m => m.Course.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query works in my sample:

```
var res = multiCourseDetails.GroupBy(k => k.MultiCourseID)
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Name = multiCourses
                    .FirstOrDefault(q => q.MultiCourseID == t.Key).Name,
                Courses = string.Join(", ", t.Join(courses, q => q.CourseID, w => w.CourseID, (r, y) => y.Name))
            });
```

The names of the collections I used are related to the tables you posted in your question.